# Setting X11 "type" property for xmessage

Tags: x11

Is it possible to set the [X11 "type" property (_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE)](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/latest/ar01s05.html) of a dialog box generated by the `xmessage` command to "dialog" (which I would have thought would be the default)?

In other words, I want to create a dialog box from the command line and set the _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE attribute:

```
> xmessage "message text" &   # (plus relevant xmessage opts)
[1] 25396                     # (or similar)
> # command to set _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE for this window?
```

Answer (score 5):

To set a window type:

```
xprop -id <your-window-ID> \
      -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE 32a \
      -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DIALOG
```

I don't know an easy automated way to find out window ID of an `xmessage` window. You can do this:

```
xmessage -xrm <some-dummy-name>:<some-unique-string> <your-other-options>
```

`-xrm` is an old generic X11 resource management option. `xmessage` understands it and ignores unknown resources, so you can pass anything you like.

Then you can use `xlsclients -l` and use some kind of perl script to search for a window ID that has `some-unique-string` in its command.

Comment: That is at once clever and extremely hacky.